# Can I log Subversion revisions inclusive to a single calendar day?

Tags: svn

I'm attempting to list the revisions from a Subversion repository for a given calendar day. The [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.keywords) explains that a date-only will expand to mean "midnight" of that day (`00:00:00`)

> Subversion resolves that date to the most recent revision of the repository as of that date

No revisions can occur in a day before it begins. Subversion seems intent on providing *some* revision for this query. So, it will provide the last revision from the previous day!

```
$ svn log -r {2015-09-11} -q -l 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r100 | anthony | 2015-09-10 15:17:50 -0400 (Thu, 10 Sep 2015)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It doesn't help providing an upper limit, because it's still doing the "recent" revision thing on the lower limit date.

```
$ svn log -r {2015-09-11}:{2015-09-12} -q -l 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r100 | anthony | 2015-09-10 15:17:50 -0400 (Thu, 10 Sep 2015)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The documentation makes some claim about showing an "inclusive" log, but that can't possibly be true. It searches *back* as many days as it needs to find a revision :(

> You can also use a range of dates. Subversion will find all revisions between both dates, inclusive:

Is there any way to log the revisions inclusive to a single calendar day without greping?

```
$ svn log -r {2015-09-11}:{2015-09-12} -q | grep '2015-09-11'
r101 | anthony | 2015-09-11 12:11:35 -0400 (Fri, 11 Sep 2015)
r102 | anthony | 2015-09-11 12:13:01 -0400 (Fri, 11 Sep 2015)
r103 | anthony | 2015-09-11 12:15:43 -0400 (Fri, 11 Sep 2015)
```

Comment: I can't trust your `svn log -r {2015-09-11}:{2015-09-12}` after `svn log -r {2015-09-11}:{2015-09-12} -q`, BTW: they are contradictory

Comment: I faked these logs for the internet. They are based on real logs. I also limited output, where appropriate, to show the behavior.

Comment: I updated the command line examples to be more likely to produce the **faked** output. Hope that helps. I don't intend to mislead anyone. I don't want to paste my repository history onto the Internet.

Comment: OK, I see now... We can remove our earlier comments

Comment: Regarding "The documentation makes some claim about showing an "inclusive" log, but that can't possibly be true" - sad, but that **IS  true**; just for slightly different task "show revisions in $DATE=%Y-%M-%D, even if first record will be dirty or why `svn log %DATE` doesn't show my revisions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SVN 1.8+, you have to use `--search` (embedded in SVN grep-style filter) parameter in order to get only subset of output ("without first revision" by convention)

```
svn log -r {2015-09-11}:{2015-09-12} --search 2015-09-11
```